# Get IP version from packet data

Tags: c, ip, packet-sniffers, packet-capture

The pcap callback function returns the IP header and data as follows:

```
void packet_handler(u_char* param, const struct pcap_pkthdr* header, const u_char* pkt_data);
```

My understanding is the first 4 bits of the pkt_data is the IP version from which I can determine it is is IPv4 or IPv6. However, I've tried a few different ways to read the first 4 bits and I'm getting data that does not make sense.

For example, I defined the following structure:

```
struct ipdata {
    u_char version : 4;
    u_char dontcare : 4;
};
```

And then I tried to get the ip version using this code:

```
ipdata* pipdata;
pipdata = (ipdata*) pkt_data;
ip_ver = pipdata->version;
printf(" %d ", ip_ver);
```

The above method prints values of 3, 6, 9, 8 and 12. If I watch the traffic at the same time in Wireshark I see that most of the packets are IPv6.

Could someone who has done this clarify how would I go about reading the IP version?

Comment: what do you mean by "does not make sense"? What values are you getting?

Comment: What is your "a few different ways"? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The IP version *should* be known from the layer below it. Just getting it from the first bytes is not reliable.

Comment: Hmmm, the first data may be the ETHERNET address. [Programming with pcapTCPDUMP/LIBPCAP public repository](https://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html)

Comment: Thank you for all the responses. I added one of the ways I tried to get the first 4 bits and the output I am seeing.

Comment: Thank you, MikeCAT and Cheatah. I have confirmed that the pkt_data starts with the sniff_ethernet structure followed by the sniff_ip structure that contains ip_vhl.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out the answer. Npcap returns the entire ethernet packet, so the first 14 bytes are the Ethernet header:

```
/* Length of the Ethernet Header (Data Link Layer) */
#define ETHERNET_HEADER_LEN 14 

/* Ethernet addresses are 6 bytes */
#define ETHER_ADDR_LEN  6

/* Ethernet header */
struct sniff_ethernet {
    u_char ether_dhost[ETHER_ADDR_LEN]; /* Destination host address (i.e. Destination MAC Address) */
    u_char ether_shost[ETHER_ADDR_LEN]; /* Source host address (i.e. Source MAC Address) */
    u_short ether_type; /* IP? ARP? RARP? etc */
};
```

You can figure out whether it is an IPv4 or IPv6 packet by looking at the ether_type in the above structure rather than the version in the IP header, such as:

```
/* Common ethernet types in Hex*/
#define ETHERNET_TYPE_IPv4 0x0800
#define ETHERNET_TYPE_IPv6 0x86DD

u_short eth_type;
ethernet = (struct sniff_ethernet*)(pkt_data);
eth_type = ntohs(ethernet->ether_type);

if (eth_type == ETHERNET_TYPE_IPv4) {
    ipv4_handler(pkt_data);
}
else if (eth_type == ETHERNET_TYPE_IPv6)
{
    ipv6_handler(pkt_data);
}
```

The IP header starts right after the ethernet header, so you can get it with code such as the following example for an IPv6 packet:

```
/* IPv6 header */
typedef struct ipv6_header
{
    unsigned int
        version : 4,
        traffic_class : 8,
        flow_label : 20;
    uint16_t length;
    uint8_t  next_header;
    uint8_t  hop_limit;
    struct in6_addr saddr;
    struct in6_addr daddr;
} ipv6_header;

const ipv6_header* iph;

iph = (ipv6_header*)(pkt_data + ETHERNET_HEADER_LEN);
```

From there you can access the version and other information about the IP header. See this post for more information: [Getting Npcap IPv6 source and destination addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66784119/getting-npcap-ipv6-source-and-destination-addresses?noredirect=1#comment118057497_66784119)