# Getting Npcap IPv6 source and destination addresses

Tags: c++, windows, pcap, libpcap, npcap

I'm trying to get the source and destination addresses for all packets using the npcap SDK (https://nmap.org/npcap/) in Windows. It works for IPv4, but it is returning the same address for the source and destination for IPv6 addresses. Here is the code for my packet_handler callback function:

```
void packet_handler(u_char* param, const struct pcap_pkthdr* header, const u_char* pkt_data)
{
    u_int ip_len;
    u_short eth_type;
    const sniff_ip* iph;
    const in6_addr* orig_saddr6;
    const in6_addr* orig_daddr6;
    in6_addr swapped_saddr;
    in6_addr swapped_daddr;

    const struct sniff_ethernet* ethernet; /* The ethernet header */

    ip_len = header->len;
    ethernet = (struct sniff_ethernet*)(pkt_data);
    eth_type = ntohs(ethernet->ether_type);

    iph = (sniff_ip*)(pkt_data +
        14); //length of ethernet header

    if (eth_type == 0x0800) {
        char str_saddr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(iph->ip_src), str_saddr, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);

        char str_daddr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(iph->ip_dst), str_daddr, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
        printf("%s %s\n", str_saddr, str_daddr);
    }
    else if (eth_type == 0x86DD)
    {
        char str_saddr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
        orig_saddr6 = (const in6_addr*)&(iph->ip_src);
        ipv6_sbyteswap(orig_saddr6, &swapped_saddr);
        inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &swapped_saddr, str_saddr, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);

        char str_daddr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
        orig_daddr6 = (const in6_addr*)&(iph->ip_dst);
        ipv6_dbyteswap(orig_daddr6, &swapped_daddr);
        inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &swapped_daddr, str_daddr, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);

        printf("%s %s\n", str_saddr, str_daddr);
    }
}
```

The problem I am seeing is that the saddr and daddr are the same IP address when the eth_type is for IPv6 packets (e.g. eth_type == 0x86DD), except the bytes are in a different order. I've doubled and tripled check the code, but when I check the iph->ip_src and iph->ip_dst I see the same types, so it looks like the npcap library is returning the same address. I don't see anything I can do to change the behavior. Has anyone ran into this?

Comment: I don't know anything about npcap, but ipv4 and ipv6 hearders are different. Your code is treating everything as an ipv4 header and just blindly casting ipv4 addresses to ipv6 addresses which is obviously not going to work.

Comment: Luke, could you clarify what you mean? I'm getting the eth_type and checking that to determine when I have IPv6 packets. If the packets are IPv4 (eth_type == 0x0800) I use the IPv4 calls, and when they are IPv6 (eth_type == 0x86DD) I use the IPv6 calls. I'm only casting to IPv6 when the eth_type specifies they are IPv6.

Comment: I'm assuming npcap gives you a buffer of the ethernet frame. This is going to contain an IP frame. The IP frame is going to have a header, and the format of that header differs between IPv4 and IPv6. Given the context, I'm assuming sniff_ip represents an IPv4 header. That's going to contain garbage values when you're dealing with IPv6 data. You need to cast to an IPv6 header structure. I assume there must be something like sniff_ip6 for this case.

Comment: Thank you, Luke. That makes sense. I've been digging around to find documentation that tells me what the pkt_data structure is for an IPv6 packet, but I haven't been able to find anything yet. Your feedback helps point me in the right direction. I'm digging through the npcap and libpcap source code now, but I haven't found the code that calls the callback yet.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the problem, you have to cast the IP header using the appropriate IPv6 structure. Here is the working code:

```
/* IPv4 header */
typedef struct ip4_header {
    u_char  ver_ihl;        // Version (4 bits) + Internet header length (4 bits)
    u_char  tos;            // Type of service 
    u_short tlen;           // Total length 
    u_short identification; // Identification
    u_short flags_fo;       // Flags (3 bits) + Fragment offset (13 bits)
    u_char  ttl;            // Time to live
    u_char  proto;          // Protocol
    u_short crc;            // Header checksum
    ip_address  saddr;      // Source address
    ip_address  daddr;      // Destination address
    u_int   op_pad;         // Option + Padding
}ip4_header;

/* IPv6 header */
typedef struct ipv6_header
{
    unsigned int
        version : 4,
        traffic_class : 8,
        flow_label : 20;
    uint16_t length;
    uint8_t  next_header;
    uint8_t  hop_limit;
    struct in6_addr saddr;
    struct in6_addr daddr;
} ipv6_header;

/* Process IPv6 packets*/
void ipv6_handler(const u_char* pkt_data) {
    const ipv6_header* iph;

    iph = (ipv6_header*)(pkt_data + ETHERNET_HEADER_LEN);
    char str_saddr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    memset(str_saddr, 0, sizeof(str_saddr));
    inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &iph->saddr, str_saddr, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);

    char str_daddr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    memset(str_daddr, 0, sizeof(str_saddr));
    inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &iph->daddr, str_daddr, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);

    printf("%s %s\n", str_saddr, str_daddr);
}

void packet_handler2(u_char* param, const struct pcap_pkthdr* header, const u_char* pkt_data)
{

    const struct sniff_ethernet* ethernet; /* The ethernet header */

    u_short eth_type;
    ethernet = (struct sniff_ethernet*)(pkt_data);
    eth_type = ntohs(ethernet->ether_type);

    if (eth_type == ETHERNET_TYPE_IPv4) {
        ipv4_handler(pkt_data);
    }
    else if (eth_type == ETHERNET_TYPE_IPv6)
    {
        ipv6_handler(pkt_data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the ipv6_sbyteswap function. Just follow the below code and it will work.
It works in my case.

```
else if (eth_type == 0x86DD)
    {
        char str_saddr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
        inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(iph->ip_src), str_saddr, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
        char str_daddr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
        inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(iph->ip_dst), str_daddr, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
        printf("%s %s\n", str_saddr, str_daddr);
    }
```